# Use a string outside of if and else statement to set string value

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, testing, automation

I just have a simple enough question on an issue I'm having. I am trying to set a string value to `"0"` if a webelement isn't present else the string is the the webelement value (using `getText`). However I can't seem to use these values ouside the *if and else* statement. How do I do this?

Here is my code

```
String players_in_game = null;

public void join_game_user_increases_register() throws Exception {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers.getDriver(), 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(countdownLabel));

    if (!num_of_players_in_game.isDisplayed()) {
        String players_in_game = "0";
    } else {
        String players_in_game = num_of_players_in_game.getText();
    }

    System.out.println(players_in_game);
    int first_num = Integer.parseInt(players_in_game);
```

Comment: `players_in_game` is already declared as `String` in the first line, so remove it from the if and else statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use code below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers.getDriver(), 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(countdownLabel));

String players_in_game = "0";
if(num_of_players_in_game.isDisplayed()){
   players_in_game = num_of_players_in_game.getText();   
}

System.out.println(players_in_game);
int first_num = Integer.parseInt(players_in_game);
```

Or:

```
String players_in_game = num_of_players_in_game.isDisplayed() ? num_of_players_in_game.getText() : "0";
```

Or:

```
List<WebElements> num_of_players_in_game = driver.findElements(By....);
String players_in_game = num_of_players_in_game.size()==0 ? "0": num_of_players_in_game.get(0).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks, im coming into an issue here aswell though, If the element num_of_players_in_game cant be found the test is failing?

Comment: Yes, num_of_players_in_game.isDisplayed() will throw error if element not exist. Check my answer update. Simply use findElements and check size.

Answer (score 1):

Since your already declare that variable as a class member in the first line of your code, simple remove the `String` to not re-declare that name as a local variable but use the field instead:

```
if(!num_of_players_in_game.isDisplayed()){
    players_in_game = "0";
} else {
    players_in_game = num_of_players_in_game.getText();
}
```

Comment: No idea who downvoted, but I upvoted to compensate. Not out of pity, but because you are right. OP has defined the `players_in_game` field on class-level, so removing the `String` means it will use that field in the method. I would personally remove the class-level String and use the first snippet provided by _@sers_, but that doesn't mean your answer is wrong for the code OP provided.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen at first I didn't see the field declaration because of a formatting error in the question, so I provided the same code with a local variable. Then I edited the whole thing, assuming using a field would be the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Java allows variable shadowing at class level. So, you can actually declare a variable which has the same name as a class variable inside any method. In your case, the variable name is `players_in_game`.

You can define that variable once again in a method but scope of that new variable will be different. So, if you want to set that class level String inside a method, do not define a new variable and use the class level variable.

So just use the below code:

```
if (!num_of_players_in_game.isDisplayed()) {
    players_in_game = "0";
} else {
    players_in_game = num_of_players_in_game.getText();
}
```

Already others have answered with code. I just wanted to explain the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
String players_in_game = null;

public void join_game_user_increases_register() throws Exception {

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers.getDriver(), 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(countdownLabel));

try {
    if (num_of_players_in_game.isDisplayed()) {
        String players_in_game = num_of_players_in_game.getText();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    String players_in_game = "0";
}

System.out.println(players_in_game);
int first_num = Integer.parseInt(players_in_game);
```